# What does 'Operator initials error' mean?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am reading an array of data from my sheet, updating elements and then using setValues to plug back in - with no luck.
Simply reading the array and then using setValues immediately to set back the read data without changing anything is resulting in the same issue

I have tried debugging my call, outputting the data to logger to check for obvious issues. Eliminating the line which sets the values stops the error.

```
function GrabTimes(){
  var RailSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('D160 Rail Serials');
  var MaxRows = RailSheet.getMaxRows();
  var MaxColumns = RailSheet.getMaxColumns();


  var GrabData = RailSheet.getRange(1, 1, MaxRows, MaxColumns);
  //var GrabDataValues = GrabData.getValues();
  Logger.log(MaxColumns);

  var GrabDataValues = RailSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  GrabData.setValues(GrabDataValues);

  /*
  for (var n=0;n<MaxRows;n++){
    var StartTimeValue=GrabDataValues[n][20];
    var EndTimeValue=GrabDataValues[n][21];

    if (GrabDataValues[n][1]=="TRUE" && StartTimeValue==""){
      GrabDataValues[n][20]=new Date();
    }
    if (GrabDataValues[n][18]=="TRUE" && StartTimeValue==""){
      GrabDataValues[n][21]=new Date();
    }
   }
   */
}
```

I'd expect the code to simply grab the data and then allow it to be set back without any changes at the very least?
I'd expect the error message to highlight the erroneous line, though it simply reports 'operator initial error'. Its only through trial and error I've managed to pin-point the line flagging the issue.

Comment: how did you get `MaxRows` and MaxColumns`?

Comment: Hi Alberto, I've updated as above to show  - thank you.

Comment: I believe the answer @Cooper gave should work for you. but just so you know, `getMaxRows()` and `getMaxColumns()` will get the number of rows available, with or without content, so if you have 1000 blank rows you'll be getting them in `maxRows`, consider using `getDataRange()`

Answer (score 2):

Try using `RailSheet.getDataRange().getValues()` It will get all the data that's on the sheet.

As a test try this:

```
function GrabTimes(){
  var RailSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('D160 Rail Serials');
  var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('target');
  var GrabData = RailSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  targetSheet.getRange(1,1,GrabData.length,GrabData[0].length).setValues(GrabData);
}
```

Comment: Hi Cooper, thanks - tried that as above and get an error message of 'The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 23 but the range has 33'. If I hardcode the columns to 23 I again get the 'Operator initials error'. Any ideas would be most appreciated.